# My public class isn't declared within the program

Tags: java

With the program below I had created, it won't allow me to run it as it claims that the class is public and should be declared. How can I fix it so that I can run my program successfully? Thanks.

Here is my full code :

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    int size;
    // This is where the object is created in which the different dogs are given an attribute which in this case is a name which is a variable type string.
    public void bark() {
        if (size > 60) {
            System.out.println(name+"says ruff!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(name +" says yip!");
        }
    }
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("woooooohoooooooooo mans playing games");
    }
}
// This public class is the second class in which the method is tested and its where the different dogs are named and new dogs arrive.
public class DogTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        dog1.name = "Bart";
        dog1.size = 100;
        Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[2]; // here is where the array of the dogs begins and it has already set the position to 2 
        myDogs[0] = new Dog();
        // my dogs is a new class 
        myDogs[1] = dog1;
        myDogs[0].name = "Fred";
        myDogs[0].size = 43;
        // This is where an array with the different dogs names were stored - these can count as attributes. 
        int x = 0;
        while (x < myDogs.length) {
            myDogs[x].bark();
            myDogs[x].play();
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your Dog class?

Comment: And when you show us the Dog class, can you include the file names for each class? Public classes need to be in their own, appropriately named, file. Eg. `public class Dog` needs to be in `Dog.java`.

Comment: class Dog {
    String name;
    int size;

Comment: Please provide all relevant classes and their names.

Comment: this is what I have so far as the dog class

Comment: @WendingPeng the class dog (in the comment above)  is the only class I have within the program

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas how would I go about doing that and the comment below the first contains the class names

Comment: Please [edit] your question with all relevant information, not provide code in comments that people will miss

Comment: alright let me edit the question

Comment: @cricket_007 I have now included the full program I have created above if that helpss

Comment: And what is the name of this file? `DogTestDrive.java` I assume? That's your issue, as mentioned

Comment: @cricket_007 If the file name really is "DogTestDrive.java", then OP wouldn't have this issue :P.

Comment: @Tom Rather I meant that there should ideally be two files, not one with both classes. Regardless of nesting.

Comment: The filename needs to match the **single allowed** (which is what you did) `public class` in it. Make sure it's called `DogTestDrive.java` and not `Dog.java.

Answer (score 0):

You declared both of your classes i the same file.

The error message said, that top level public classes should be declared in their own file, having the same name as the  class, just as @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas mentioned in the comments.

So, you have to create a second file, named `Dog.java`, as @cricket_007 mentioned in the comments, and move `Dog` class in it.

Comment: Wrong, OP doesn't need to create a _second_ file. A single file is fine when names correctly.

Comment: Yeah, you can tweak things like that. But the generally preferred way to do things is this. EG One could move class `Dog` to be an inner `static class`...

Comment: It is ok (and preferable) to explain that each class should be in its own file, public or not, but it is not ok to provide misleading information. It is not the issue that both classes are in the same file, only the file name is wrong.

Comment: And what exactly makes you saying that the filename is wrong? It might be that the class names are incorrect... BTW Let's just say, there are multiple solution to the problem, and my may not be the best, but it is a working one...

Comment: It's not that important if the class name is misspelled or the file name, the issue is still the same: class name (of the public class) and file name are not equal. **"my may not be the best"** - I guess you misunderstood me, the fix (a file for each class) is ok and even recommended, but your explanation for the issue isn't correct. It is _not_ the problem that `Dog` is also in that file. It is also kind of sad that OP still didn't provide the currently used file name, but that's nothing we can change :/.

Comment: @TOM So how do I go about changing the class